# PHP: Is there an elegant way to foreach through multiple items (groups) at a time?

Tags: php, foreach

Given an array of *N* items:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
```

What's the most elegant way to loop through in groups of *M* items (assuming *N* is divisible by *M*)?

I tried

```
foreach (array_chunk($arr, 2) as list($first, $second)) {
    // do stuff with $first and $second
}
```

but this resulted in a syntax error.

In other words, I want to emulate what in Tcl would look like this:

```
set arr [a b c d e f]
foreach {first second} $arr {
    // do stuff with $first and $second
}
```

For now I've resorted to the obvious measure:

```
foreach (array_chunk($arr, 2) as $group) {
    $first  = $group[0];
    $second = $group[1];
    // do stuff with $first and $second
}
```

But I'm hoping someone has a more elegant method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd alter your last variant to

```
foreach (array_chunk($arr, 2) as $group) {
    list( $first, $second) = $group;
    // do stuff with $first and $second
}
```

Any other solution I thought about, would be more complex, like

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < ceil(count($arr)/2) ; $i++) {
    $first = $arr[$i*2];
    $second = $arr[$i*2+1];
}
```

Comment: OMG! I answered the same thing on same timestamp

Comment: How did I not think of that, after going all the way with `array_chunk` and `list`, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');

$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 2);
while (list($first, $second) = each($chunks))
{
    ...
}
```

if you put `array_chunk()` into `each()` it will produce an infinite loop :(

Comment: Interesting alternative; shame that condensing it causes an infinite loop. Thanks for experimenting though! This would be useful if chunking can happen in an earlier part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there is no syntactic sugar like the way you wanted.  However their are many ways to achieve this.

### For loop

```
for($i=0; $first=$arr[$i], $second=$arr[$i+1], $i<$len; $i+=2){
}
```

### Foreach loop

```
foreach (array_chunk($arr, 2) as $chunk) {
    list($first, $second) = $chunk;
}
```

See the `foreach` form. Its not much different than your syntax.

### While loop

```
$i=0;
while(list($first, $second) = array_slice($arr, ($i+=2)-2, 2)) {
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure who answered first; I accepted @bukfixart's answer but for you I'll look at some of your other SO answers and upvote one or two that I personally find interesting.

Comment: Its okay @acheong87. I have added a while loop version too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_splice`

```
while ( list($first, $second) = array_splice($arr, 0, 2) ) {
  echo $first.', '.$second.PHP_EOL;
}
```

It will throw a `notice` when `$arr` becomes empty

```
while ( !empty($arr) && list($first, $second) = array_splice($arr, 0, 2) ) {
  echo $first.', '.$second.PHP_EOL;
}
```

But this will still throw a `notice` if the size of the array is `odd`.

Comment: Ah, that's right! `array_splice` works on the referenced array but returns the extracted elements. This is great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a case to take advantage of SPL's multipleIterator:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 2);

$iterator = new MultipleIterator;
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    $iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($chunk));
}

foreach ($iterator as $values) {
    var_dump($values[0], $values[1], $values[2]);
}
```